# How to achieve 'donut holes' with paths in Raphael

Tags: vector, svg, path, raphael

I'd like to draw a shape which has holes in it such that I can `fill` the shape it and not have the holes filled with that colour (leave them transparent).

According to the [W3 path spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html):

> Compound paths (i.e., a path with multiple subpaths) are possible to allow effects such as "donut holes" in objects.

Can somebody please give a very simple example of how to perform this with a vector path in [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Thanks very much.

Comment: In fact it's not specific to Raphael but more generaly to SVG.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This turns out to be quite straightforward if you know the trick.  For example [this doesn't work](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/donut-broken.html):

```
paper.path("M 50 50 L 50 150 L 150 150 L 150 50 z" + 
          " M 75 75 L 75 125 L 125 125 L 125 75 z")
.attr("fill", "#f00");
```

But [this does work](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/donut.html)*:

```
paper.path("M 50 50 L 50 150 L 150 150 L 150 50 z" +
          " M 75 75 L 125 75 L 125 125 L 75 125 z")
.attr("fill", "#f00");
```

The difference is that for the donut to appear the the inner path has to have it's **vertices drawn in reverse order** to the outer path (ie. draw one clockwise, the other anti-clockwise).  A tidbit I found on the [text.xml.svg.devel archives](http://osdir.com/ml/text.xml.svg.devel/2002-07/msg00223.html).

(*) At least, it works in Chrome, Opera and Firefox 4.0 beta, but not in 3.6

Comment: I am trying to use this technique to fill a circular doughnut, any idea how to get the circle function to draw in reverse so that it fills correctly?

Comment: @Neil As far as I'm aware you have to use paths to make this work.

Comment: @robertc thanks I did indeed achieve this with paths, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. The result (with differents coordinates) can be seen here : http://jsfiddle.net/cWHdk/2/

Comment: Hi @ robertc. I am looking for the opposite of your solution please. And here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847767/how-to-change-an-svgs-complex-paths-that-have-duplicated-paths-for-each-line-to

Answer (score 4):

To make this work in Firefox 3.6, you need to close the hole; i.e. make the coordinates join back to themselves when defining the inner boundary. Curiously, this doesn't appear necessary for the outer boundary.

```
paper.path("M 50 50 L 50 150 L 150 150 L 150 50 z" +
          " M 75 75 L 125 75 L 125 125 L 75 125 L 75 75 z")
.attr("fill", "#f00");
```

Just a quick note to follow up on the comment - the clockwise/counter-clockwise concept might seem strange at first, but it's pretty standard throughout GIS / CAD technologies.

Comment: Hi @ Ben. I am looking for the opposite of your solution please. And here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847767/how-to-change-an-svgs-complex-paths-that-have-duplicated-paths-for-each-line-to

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct way to do this is setting the attribute "fill-rule" to the value "evenodd". Take a look at the [svg spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperties):

Don't try to set it with "Raphael.Element.attr()". It doesn't work. I use the jQuery.attr() function instead:

```
// assuming paper is a Raphael.Paper object
path = paper.path('Mx,y{some path commands for the main shape}Z'
                  +'Mx,y{some path commands for the hole}Z'
);

// this doesn't work
path.attr({'fill-rule': 'evenodd'});
// neither this
path.attr({fillRule: 'evenodd'});

// if you inspect the object returned by paper.path
// you can see it has a reference to the DOM element
console.debug(path)

// so a bit of jQuery and it's done
$(path[0]).attr('fill-rule', 'evenodd');
```

I have used this on complex paths with successful results.

Comment: Just wanted to give a non-jQuery update to this:


`path[0].setAttribute('fill-rule', 'evenodd');`


works

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to do circular donuts, great easy plugin [Raphael-donut-plugin](https://github.com/arturjaworski/raphael-donut-plugin)

Gist:

```
Raphael.fn.donut = function(x, y, innerRadius, outerRadius) {
  y -= outerRadius;
  return this.path('M'+x+' '+y+'a'+outerRadius+' '+outerRadius +
      ' 0 1 0 1 0m-1 '+
      (outerRadius - innerRadius)+
      'a'+innerRadius+' '+innerRadius+
      ' 0 1 1 -1 0');
};
```

Comment: if you add a fiddle example that would be great