# svg - draw hollow rectangle(rect donut)?

Tags: javascript, svg

Can anybody help me with drawing hollow rectangle with svg WITHOUT using any js lib(e.g. Raphael)?
In basic, it should be same idea as "donut shape" but rectangle.
something like this:

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kju3Q/5/ check this fiddle, do you want something like this for your application ?

Comment: @ViralShah, The only problem with that is that it's not hollow, it just appears to be.

Comment: See the answer here, and modify for rectangle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972347/raphael-js-converting-pie-graph-to-donut-graph/7975226#7975226 It should be easy.

Comment: would it be too challenging do it without Raphael js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gw28/):

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <path d="M10,10h100v100h-100zM20,20v80h80v-80z" fill="yellow" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 8):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/na6hA/)

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2624 1462" width="1312" height="736" id="svg2">

  <path d="M 80,112 l 528,0 0,528 -528,0 z m -64,-64.000003 656,0 0,656.000023 -656,0 z" fill="gold" stroke="black" fill-rule="evenodd" />

</svg>
```

The path winds in one direction outside and the other inside and the evenodd fill-rule cuts out the middle.

Comment: That's brilliant! Now.. how would you do that with circles?