# Custom Shaped Pie Chart

Tags: css, html, graph, charts, svg

I am trying to create a dynamic pie graph that is arc shaped with css. The following graph represents 100% of the data:

[image: arc shaped pie graph]

I've done quite a bit of researching/Google searching, and I'm struggling to find something that would work.

This looks pretty close: http://blakek.us/labs/jquery/css3-pie-graph-timer/ but I'm not sure how I would get a half circle out of that.

Comment: You can make that with only a few changes to the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141126/simple-donut-chart-with-raphael

Comment: Can you give a little more information about how that solution would fit?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Raphael library is what I needed. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VdTH4/228/