# Filling a path depends on the drawing order

Tags: javascript, raphael

I need to draw an inverted triangle inside another triangle, using Raphaël.js. Similar to the following ASCII art:

```
   /\
  /__\
 /\  /\
/__\/__\
```

The only difference being that I'm drawing it sideways (with the top to the right), in order to apply rotations to it.

Depending on the order in which I draw the lines in the `path` string, the center may, or may not, be colored with the filling color.

**HTML**

```
<div id="paper"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#paper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px
}
```

**JavaScript (filling the inside)**

```
function triangles(paper, x, y, w, h, attr) {
    var cx = x + w / 2,
        cy = y + h / 2,
        path = ["M", x, y, "L", x + w, cy, x, y + h, "Z",
                "M", cx, y + h/4, "L", cx,
                y + h*3/4, x, cy, "Z"].join(" ");
    return paper.path(path).attr(attr);
}

var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("paper"), 200, 200);
triangles(paper, 20, 20, 80, 80, {
    fill: "#abcabd"
});
```

**JavaScript (leaves the inside blank)**

```
function triangles(paper, x, y, w, h, attr) {
    var cx = x + w / 2,
        cy = y + h / 2,
        path = ["M", x + w, cy, "L", x, y, x, y + h, "Z",
                "M", cx, y + h/4, "L", cx,
                y + h*3/4, x, cy, "Z"].join(" ");
    return paper.path(path).attr(attr);
}

var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("paper"), 200, 200);
triangles(paper, 20, 20, 80, 80, {
    fill: "#abcabd"
});
```

---

Note that the only difference is the first two points.

```
// Fills the inside:
"M", x, y, "L", x + w, cy
// Doesn't fill the inside:
"M", x + w, cy, "L", x, y
```

---

#### What is causing Raphaël to *misbehave*?

#### How do I determine beforehand if the figure is going to be filled?

---

**Demo**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHzqP/)

Just toggle the comments between the two blocks of JavaScript.

Comment: @A.S.Roma Sure, I'll post the link in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably related to fill-rule: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/painting.html#FillRuleProperty .

Comment: Your answer led me to this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3365621/2088822), which seems to explain the problem I experienced.