# how to rebuild raphael js path

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, raphael

I have a specific problem with Raphael JS.

I'm drawing a donut element (similar to this link [How to achieve 'donut holes' with paths in Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349651/how-to-achieve-donut-holes-with-paths-in-raphael))

```
var hole_draw = paper.path('M0,0 H1340V680H0ZM852,283H994V391H852'); 
-- some work over this hole, clicks, etc.
```

And then I have some jQuery click events which update the container size and I'd like to rebuild the coords for the hole_draw element.

Is there any specific method to do this  without deleting it and re-creating it? Something like:

```
hole_draw.rebuild('M0,0 H440V280H0ZM352,281H394V791H352'); //is this exist?
```

And keep all the events related to this?

Hope there is a clean solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use the scale method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use animate function

hole_draw.animate({path:"M"+x+" "+y+" "+z});